# Determining the IP address of the node that executes the UrlFetchApp call

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

For a Web API call via UrlFetchApp in a Google Apps Script I have to submit the HTTP client IP (via HTTP-GET) for authentification (namecheap.com API).

Is there a way to determine the IP address of the node that will execute the UrlFetchApp call for adding it to the query URL?

Comment: No. I used a different API from a different provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, Google does provide you with a [range of IP addresses](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt) through which the call will be made:

```
8.8.4.0/24
8.8.8.0/24
8.34.208.0/20
8.35.192.0/20
23.236.48.0/20
23.251.128.0/19
34.0.0.0/15
34.2.0.0/16
34.3.0.0/23
34.3.3.0/24
34.3.4.0/24
34.3.8.0/21
34.3.16.0/20
34.3.32.0/19
34.3.64.0/18
34.3.128.0/17
34.4.0.0/14
34.8.0.0/13
34.16.0.0/12
34.32.0.0/11
34.64.0.0/10
34.128.0.0/10
35.184.0.0/13
35.192.0.0/14
35.196.0.0/15
35.198.0.0/16
35.199.0.0/17
35.199.128.0/18
35.200.0.0/13
35.208.0.0/12
35.224.0.0/12
35.240.0.0/13
64.15.112.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.22.228.0/23
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.64.0/19
70.32.128.0/19
72.14.192.0/18
74.114.24.0/21
74.125.0.0/16
104.154.0.0/15
104.196.0.0/14
104.237.160.0/19
107.167.160.0/19
107.178.192.0/18
108.59.80.0/20
108.170.192.0/18
108.177.0.0/17
130.211.0.0/16
136.112.0.0/12
142.250.0.0/15
146.148.0.0/17
162.216.148.0/22
162.222.176.0/21
172.110.32.0/21
172.217.0.0/16
172.253.0.0/16
173.194.0.0/16
173.255.112.0/20
192.158.28.0/22
192.178.0.0/15
193.186.4.0/24
199.36.154.0/23
199.36.156.0/24
199.192.112.0/22
199.223.232.0/21
207.223.160.0/20
208.65.152.0/22
208.68.108.0/22
208.81.188.0/22
208.117.224.0/19
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.73.80.0/20
216.239.32.0/19
2001:4860::/32
2404:6800::/32
2404:f340::/32
2600:1900::/28
2606:73c0::/32
2607:f8b0::/32
2620:11a:a000::/40
2620:120:e000::/40
2800:3f0::/32
2a00:1450::/32
2c0f:fb50::/32
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections

Comment: Me too. The addresses I logged are 107.178.192.138, 107.178.192.142, 107.178.192.146

Comment: Updated with current list of ranges