# Accessing IP-restricted API from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Apps Script to access an API that is IP address restricted ([Vitelity](http://apihelp.vitelity.net/)), in addition to requiring a username and password.  I've searched through the documentation, and haven't found an answer to whether or not Google Apps Script will always originate requests from a single IP address (today 66.102.6.53), or if it the requesting IP will vary from day to day.

I wrote and am calling the following function:

```
function getVitelityBalance() {
  var txtResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.vitelity.net/api.php?login=ourUserName&pass=ourPassword&cmd=balance").getContentText();  
  doc = Xml.parse(txtResponse, true);
  balance = doc.response;
  Logger.log(balance);
};
```

The execution transcript returns a response saying that the IP address from which the request is made isn't authorized.  Obviously I can whitelist this IP address, but will Google Apps always originate the request from the same IP address, or will this be changing all the time, such that this code will always break?

```
[14-10-07 08:43:25:201 PDT] Starting execution
[14-10-07 08:43:25:306 PDT] UrlFetchApp.fetch([http://api.vitelity.net/api.php?login=ourUserName&pass=ourPassword=balance]) [0.084 seconds]
[14-10-07 08:43:25:307 PDT] HTTPResponse.getContentText() [0 seconds]
[14-10-07 08:43:25:331 PDT] Xml.parse([ <html>
    <body>
            <font face="verdana" size="2">Vitelity Communications API. Unauthorized access prohibited. All commands are logged along with IP and username.<br><br><pre style="font-size: 12px; font-family: verdana">
        **x[[Unauthorized access attempt from 66.102.6.53[[x, true]) [0.024 seconds]**
[14-10-07 08:43:25:332 PDT] Logger.log([undefined, []]) [0 seconds]
[14-10-07 08:43:25:333 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.112 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a definitive answer, but this link might be helpful:  [Google Documentation - IP address ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_google_cloud_sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the IP address of the node that executes the UrlFetchApp call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708477/determining-the-ip-address-of-the-node-that-executes-the-urlfetchapp-call)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question, but you probably don't want to rely on a value remaining the same if you can't verify it yourself. Can you configure the API server to accept an authorization header? You could then make your UrlFetchApp.fetch() request with options and set the header to do the authorization using a token that you generate yourself. You could also encode it directly into the URL of the request itself, though this is less secure. Just an idea, since it sounds like you're in control of the API server, if you can whitelist IP addresses.

The only other solution that comes to mind, given what you've said above, is experimentation: see if the IP address changes or doesn't from fetch to fetch and from day to day. Put in some error handling that automatically notifies you in the event of a failed authorization. I have a few scripts that are set to email me whenever they throw an exception, which isn't often, fortunately. In your case, you may be able to get by this way, only changing the IP address on your whitelist rarely. Of course, I have no way of knowing how practical this is for your particular problem—it's a pretty obvious (and slightly lazy) workaround, too. Others may have better answers!

Comment: There are advanced parameters that can be sent with the HTTP Request including a **headers** parameter:  [Google Documentation - Fetch with Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: Yes, I did say that: "request with options." Maybe not clearly? To the OP, you can pass an object as the options parameter to fetch() with the header field set to, if you like, another object containing whatever headers you need to specify. Sandy's link will lead you to examples.