# How to know IP of UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, ip, ip-address, urlfetch

I've searched for similar questions here on Stackoverflow but they didn't give an answer.

I make a UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) request to some api service, but the service probably bans this requesting IP. I need to whitelist it. I know there are lots of IPs which google apps use, but for now I need to determine at lease this one which is used for this specific call.

I tried this script to figure out the requests:

```
function getR(){
  var url = 'https://my.APIENDPOINTURL'
  req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options)
  Logger.log(req)
  resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  Logger.log(resp)
}
```

And it gives me this log:

[image]

Why does it show my real IP?

What's going on under the hood? I expected the real IP with UrlFetchApp uses in .getRequests() output.
Am I missing something?

Are there any tricks of knowing which IP does UrlFetchApp use?
I know that there is no this functionality as a native function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the IP address of the node that executes the UrlFetchApp call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708477/determining-the-ip-address-of-the-node-that-executes-the-urlfetchapp-call)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because, it reads "it's impossible" and just a list of possible IP addresses is given. This information is only related to my question.

Comment: Isn't `it's impossible` an answer?

Comment: That's just an opinion of one member of a community. People make mistakes often. Also, I have a question in this post why my real IP is shown.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a list of IP addresses that Apps Script may use while calling other services here - https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt

It's buried in this [JDBC article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections).

Comment: "buried" - exactly :). Thank you for that list. It was mentioned in some answers but sicne a lot of time has passed, this list is not somewhere in the article on visible place.
However, I would like to know somehow the exact IP being used by UrlFetchApp when doing a request to an external resource.

Comment: this list has ipv4 only: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog_ipv4_only.txt